# Linear Discriminant Analysis' predictions newbie question

Tags: discriminant-analysis

When I use predict.lda in R (MASS package) which discriminant function does the software choose? Say, I have 4 classes and 3 discriminant functions, does the software always use the first discrimination function (highest trace) or does it use an ensemble of the three functions?

Comment: I'm not R user but I expect that the function uses all the extracted discriminants to classify objects.

Comment: The number of discriminants is min(num_of_classes - 1, num_of_variables). But there must also be an option to extract/use a lesser number - only a subset of the first discriminants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the documentation of *predict.lda* does not shed any light on this question, but it gives a reference to "Pattern Recognition and Neural Networks" by Ripley (1996), who writes:

> Fisher’s procedure cannot tell us the threshold between the two groups in classification. It seems common practice to classify by choosing the group whose mean is nearest in the space of canonical variats. Since in that space Euclidean distance is the within-group Mahalanobis distance, this corresponds to the Bayes rule if (and only if) the prior probabilities are equal.

This refers to the decision rule on the transformed variables, i.e., after projecting the data on the $C-1$ discriminant directions, where $C$ is the number of classes. In this space, *predict.lda* thus assigns a sample to the class of the nearest class mean value.

Concerning your question, beware that R's *lda* does not yield discriminant functions, but instead a matrix *scaling* $S$ that transforms the data into a $C-1$ dimensional subspace in such a way that the classes are optimally separated. The $C$ discriminant functions $g_i$ are then

\begin{eqnarray*}
g_i(\vec{x}) & = & - \|S(\vec{x} - \vec{\mu}_i)\|^2 \\
 & = & -\underbrace{\|S\vec{x}\|^2}_{\mbox{irrelevant}} + 2\langle S\vec{x}, S\vec{\mu}_i\rangle - \|S\vec{\mu}_i\|^2
\end{eqnarray*}

where $\vec{\mu}_i$ is the mean value of class $i$, and the minus sign has been added to bring the definition in line with the usual decision rule of choosing the class with the *greatest* discriminant function $g_i(\vec{x})$. Note that the first term $\|S\vec{x}\|^2$ is the same for all classes and can be omittted in the discriminant functon, thereby leading to an actually linear discriminant function.

This is only a decision rule and does not yield any posterior probabilities. To estimate these, a probabalistic model needs to be assumed. In the case of LDA, this model is a (multivariate) Gaussian distribution for each class, but with *all covariance matrices* assumed to be *identical*. In the transformed LDA space, this common covariance matrix is the unity matrix, which can then be inserted into the normal distribution to obtain probabilities.

Remark: if you drop the assumption of a common covraince matrix and allow for class specific covariance matrices, you end with "quadratic discriminant analysis" (R function *qda*).

Comment: I don't see how this (generally correct) information answers the question.

Comment: Thanks for insisting on this point, which I hopefully have addressed in my edit. I have now explained the connection between R's LDA output and discriminant functions.

Comment: @cdalitz thank you

Comment: @Sendil As you are a new contributor, here is a suggestion: If an answer answers your queston, you should mark it as "accepted". This will remove the question from the queue of yet unanswered questions. Moreover, you can rate answers as "useful" or "not useful".